# How do you reuse Flutter views created with MaterialPageRoute builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

How do you reuse Flutter views created with MaterialPageRoute builder? Currently new views are created in the widget tree whenever Navigator.pushReplacementNamed is called. e.g. The following code will create 4 views in the widget tree:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'page1');
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'page2');
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'page1');
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'page2');
```

I would prefer only two views in the widget tree - a single instance of both page1 and page2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

push() and pushNamed() method recreate page over the current page you should use pushReplacement() and pushReplacementNamed() methods. However in this way you cannot use automatic back feature you should use pop() method or you should again some of push methods because when you you use pushReplacement() and pushReplacementNamed() methods previous page destroy and you should re-create manually.